# Cannot focus on form tags in stuts2 div after submit

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a struts2 project which uses a tabbed panel. The tabs are jsp pages within divs. When you first select the tab the javascript at the end of the page sets the focus on the desired input field. Once you hit submit though the tab comes back with no focus in the input field.
I have debugged it extensively to see what is happening, and I've noticed that the javascript at the end of the page is running, but it just cannot focus in the field. It can see the field through getElementById and even get it's value (i've tested this with alerts) but it cannot do anything TO the field. It cannot put text in either through javascript. If I click on another tab and then click back the script the focus is restored.

The submit and textfield in the tab are below:

```
<s:form id="myForm" action="myTabAction.do" method="post" validate="true" >
.
.
.
  <s:submit name="submitz" value="Save" id="billbo"
   formId="myForm" executeScripts="true"
   href="myTabAction.do?submit=Save"
   targets="myTab" showLoadingText="false"
   theme="ajax"  cssClass="buttonSmallClass"
   indicator="loadingImage_case" /> 
 .  
 .  
 .  
 <s:textfield name="testVal" maxlength="80" id="textField" cssClass="textClass"  />
```

The javascript at the end of the tab jsp is as follows:

```
.
.
.
</s:form>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var field = document.getElementById("textField");
    field.focus();
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

The relevant parts of the parent page are:

```
<s:tabbedPanel selectedTab="%{selectedTabId2}"
 id="CasePartyTabbedPanel" theme="ajax" requiredposition="left"
 cssClass="subTabedpanelClass" cssStyle="width: 710px; height: 200px;" doLayout="false"
 templateCssPath="includes/TabContainer.css">
 .
 .
 .
 <s:div label="My Label" id="myTab" 
   href="MyAction.do?param1=%{paramVal1}&param2=%{paramVal2}"
   theme="ajax" cssStyle="display:none" refreshOnShow="true"
   executeScripts="true" >
   <p>Loading...
  </s:div>
</s:tabbedPanel></td>
```

I am using struts 2.0.9 with dojo.

I really need to find out how to set the focus to the input field after a submit.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if it is a bit long winded, but I wanted to be clear.

Thanks

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the javascript at the bottom of the page as shown below and try? -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.ready(function(){
    var field = document.getElementById("textField"); 
    field.focus(); 
});
</script>
```

When the page loads, the < script > tag at the bottom of the page might get executed before the dojo completes initialization. That could be preventing the field from getting focus. So you can add the code to set the focus in dojo.ready(), which gets executed after dojo is initialized.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is the dojo.js included in your page?

Comment: There are no errors displayed anywhere. It just fails silently. I think I need to find a way to debug it. There is no dojo.js specifically in the page, I think it is included as part of the struts package. It's definately there as dojo.byId works fine.

Comment: If you are using an older version of dojo, you may have to use dojo.addOnLoad() instead of dojo.ready().

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the attribute `focusElement`

```
<s:form focusElement="textField" />
```

Comment: Thanks but the attribute is not included in v 2.0.9. Wish it was. I dont have the option of upgrading yet either.